# Macでのsqlite3の操作時に日本語入力ができない。

Tags: macos, sqlite, 日本語

Macでsqlite3の勉強をしている者です。

iTerm2でsqlite3を使っている時にselect文で条件として日本語を入力しようとしたらエンターキーを押すと消えてしまいます。原因に心当たりがある方、教えて頂きたいです。

ちなみにiTerm2でsqlite3を使っていない時は日本語も入力できます。

iTerm2でのlocaleの出力結果は以下です。

```
LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

よろしくお願いします。

実行環境は以下です。

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.1
BuildVersion:   19B88

Comment: ホームディレクトリに `.inputrc` というファイルはありますか？

Comment: 古くてかつイマイチ上手く解決してないようですが、こんな記事がありました。[Sqlite3で日本語入力する(Mac,Terminal)](https://starhoshi.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/06/07/Sqlite3%E3%81%A7%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%28Mac%2CTerminal%29), [sqlite3 で日本語を使う](https://tnomura9.exblog.jp/17529957/), [Mac で日本語の SQL を実行する](https://tnomura9.exblog.jp/17534419/)

Comment: findコマンドで調べたところ.inputrcファイルは無いです。

Comment: Sqlite3で日本語入力する(Mac,Terminal), sqlite3 で日本語を使う, Mac で日本語の SQL を実行する←こちらのサイトで試してみたのですが、できればちゃんと日本語を表示したいと思っています。以前は日本語で入力できたのですが、約２ヶ月ぶりにやってみて、日本語入力ができなくなっていました。

Comment: OSX の sqlite3 が `readline` ライブラリを利用しているのであれば、`~/.inputrc` に `set convert-meta off`, `set output-meta on`, `set input-meta on` の3行を書いてみると問題が解決するかもしれません(`libedit` を利用している場合は何も変わりません)。

Comment: .inputrcファイルの作成と書き込みの仕方がわかりません。教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 先ほど紹介いただいた https://tnomura9.exblog.jp/17534419/ のサイトの方法でなら日本語の入力ができました。ですが、できれば根本的に解決したいです。

Comment: まずは sqlite3 が readline ライブラリを利用しているかどうかを確認したいので `ldd $(which sqlite3) | grep libreadline` の実行結果を教えて下さい。

Comment: `MacPorts`からインストールの場合だったら`libedit`のようですね。[sqlite3- Port|MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/sqlite3/summary)

Comment: lddコマンドが利用できなかったのでotool -L $(which sqlite3)として実行した結果がこれです。 @rpath/libedit.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.59.0)
 @rpath/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)

Comment: libreadline をインストールして sqlite3 を再ビルドする方法がありますが、[brewで入れたsqlite3でCTRL+Rが効かない！](https://takuya-1st.hatenablog.jp/entry/2017/02/27/093659) これで問題が解決するかどうかは定かではありません。

Comment: libreadlineをでsqlite3を再ビルドしてみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac にanaconda をインストールされていませんでしょうか？　コマンドパスが anaconda のsqlite3 になっている場合、日本語入力ができないようです。私の場合、パス設定を/usr/bin/sqlite3　に変えることで、MacOS 10.14 でも日本語入力ができました。下記のサイトを参考にしました。
https://www.u.tsukuba.ac.jp/ufaqs/sqlite3/